# React final form doesn't take custom input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have the following code:

```
...
      return (
        <FormItem key={name}>
          <Label htmlFor={id}>{camelCaseToTitleCase(fieldKey)}</Label>
          {
            fieldKey === 'homePhone' 
            ?
              <Field name={`${key}.${fieldKey}.value`} validate={validate(fieldKey)}>
                {props => 
                  (
                    <>
                    <PhoneNumberInput
                      disabled={disabled}
                      data-bdd={`customer_details_field_${fieldKey}`}
                      id={id}
                      value={props.input.value}
                      // onChange={(val: string):any => console.log(val)}
                      {...props}
                    />
                    </>
                  )
                }
              </Field>
...
```

where phoneinput is:

```
const PhoneNumberInput: React.FC<PhoneNumberInputProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    disabled,
    id,
    label,
    value
  } = props

  const [updatedValue, setUpdatedValue] = useState(value)
  const DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE = 'GB'

  const handleONChange = (val: string) => {
    setUpdatedValue(val)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Label htmlFor={id}>{label}</Label>
      <PhoneInput
        disabled={disabled}
        id={id}
        defaultCountry={DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE}
        value={updatedValue}
        onChange={(phone: string) => handleONChange(phone)}
      />
      value: {updatedValue}
    </>
  )
}
```

when I submit the form the value from `PhoneNumberInput` is still coming from `props.input.value` and doesn't reflect what's being updated in `value: {updatedValue}`.

The phoneInput component does display the updated value but the same value is not sent when the from is submitted.

[image]

The value starting with +44 is what I would like to send to my BE but it still send what ever was inside `props.input.value`

Answer (score 0):

Make the phoneInput component a component of Field like this:

```
<Field
  name={`${key}.${fieldKey}.value`}
  validate={validate(fieldKey)}
  component={phoneInput}
  disabled={disabled}
  data-bdd={`customer_details_field_${fieldKey}`}
  id={id}
/>
```

It will automatically pass props to the component

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I forgot to update the onChange:

```
<PhoneNumberInput
  disabled={disabled}
  data-bdd={`customer_details_field_${fieldKey}`}
  id={id}
  value={props.input.value}
  onChange={props.input.onChange}
  {...props}
```